# Header Repetition in navigation view android

Tags: android, navigationview, android-navigationview

I have used navigation view in my app. Header in navigation view is repeated twice but i actually removed it (**app:headerLayout="@layout/header"**) in xml. And i wanna implement action(like as button) from header of navigation view.

In code i have written like this

```
    mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    headerView = mNavigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.bp_header);
    googele_plus = (ImageButton) headerView.findViewById(R.id.google_p);
    facebook = (ImageButton) headerViewfindViewById(R.id.fb);
```

Header likes below

[image: Header repetition]

I got NullPointerException error if headerView removed from image button
Any suggestion or solution would be grateful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your support library to 23.1.1 or above.

After which you can do this -

Add the headerview in the app:headerLayout="@layout/header" inside NavigationView.

Then, you can access it by,

```
    mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    View headerView = mNavigationView.getHeaderView(0)

    googele_plus = (ImageButton) headerView.findViewById(R.id.google_p);
    facebook = (ImageButton) headerView.findViewById(R.id.fb);
```

Ref : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=190226#c31

Answer (score 2):

```
    You may have header layout in xml and also you are adding header from java like 

    headerView = mNavigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.bp_header);

    So just remove above line from java and add it through the xml
    You can add following in your xml       

 <include
 android:id="@+id/header"
 layout="@layout/navigation_header" />

     and then in java create ref like below          



      googele_plus = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.google_p);
         facebook = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.fb);

     Clean and Build the project and then run
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I also got NPE while working with `NavigationView` header where I was adding headers in layout `app:headerLayout="@layout/header"` 
To get rid of this NPE I started adding header programatically like below

```
View header = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.bp_header, null);
mNavigationView.addHeaderView(header);
googele_plus = (ImageButton) header.findViewById(R.id.google_p);
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you create header 2 times. I had the same issue.

```
 headerView = mNavigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.bp_header);
```

this line ^ actually creates new View at runtime. And I believe you create the same header in XML. Try to remove that `headerView` from XML. That will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may be called that navigation view header setting function twice. So it created two times.

If you written that setting navigation header view in onStart() method remove and write in onCreate() method.

onStart will call many times if you go to some other activity and returning back.
So it will create header as much times.
Or check in your code you are calling that code more than once.

Answer (score 0):

In **KOTLIN** I have achieved by using below code.

step 1. remove  **app:headerLayout="@layout/your_header_layout"** from NavigationView.

step 2. add below code in your activity

```
var nav = nav_view.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_home)
nav?.nav_header_title?.text = "Your text "
```

Note: if you will not remove the **app:headerLayout** from NavigationView then header will be repeat twice.